# correct function handle for integral2 in matlab

Tags: matlab, function, integral

I created a function in matlab that returns a vector like

```
function w = W_1D(x,pos,h)
w=zeros(1,length(x));
        if (h~=0)
            xmpos = x-pos; 
            inds1 = (-h <= xmpos) & (xmpos < 0);
            w(inds1) = xmpos(inds1)./h + 1;
            inds2 = (0 <= xmpos) & (xmpos <= h);
            w(inds2) = -xmpos(inds2)./h + 1;
        else
            error('h shouldn't be 0')
        end
 end
```

Thus, in the end, there is a vector `w` of size `length(x)`.
Now i created a second function like

```
function f = W_2D(x,y,pos_1,pos_2,h)
  w_x = W_1D(x,pos_1,h);
  w_y = W_1D(y,pos_2,h);
  f = w_x'*w_y;
end
```

where `length(x)=length(y)`. Thus, the function `W_2D` obviously returns a matrix. 
But when I now try to evaluate the integral over a rectangular domain like e.g.

```
V = integral2(@(x,y) W_2D(x,y,2,3,h),0,10,0,10);
```

matlab returns some errors:

```
Error using integral2Calc>integral2t/tensor (line 242)
Integrand output size does not match the input size.

Error in integral2Calc>integral2t (line 56)
[Qsub,esub] = tensor(thetaL,thetaR,phiB,phiT);

Error in integral2Calc (line 10)
[q,errbnd] = integral2t(fun,xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax,optionstruct);

Error in integral2 (line 107)
Q = integral2Calc(fun,xmin,xmax,yminfun,ymaxfun,opstruct);
```

I also tried to vary something in the `W_2D`-function: instead of `f = w_x'*w_y;` 
I tried `f = w_x.'*w_y;` 
or `w_y = transpose(w_y); f = kron(w_x,w_y);`, but there is always this error with the Integrand output size-stuff. 
Can anyone explain, where my fault is?

EDIT: After Werner's hint with the keyboard debugging method, I can tell you the following.
The first step returns `w_x` of type `<1x154 double>`, `w_y` is `<1x192 double>`, `x` and `y` are both `<14x14 double>`. In the next step, `f` appears with a value of `<154x192 double>`. Then everything disappears, except `x` and `y` and the matlab-function integral2Calc.m appears in the editor and it jumps to the Function Call Stack `integral2t/tensor` and after some more steps, the error occurs here

```
    Z = FUN(X,Y);  NFE = NFE + 1;
    if FIRSTFUNEVAL
        if ~isfloat(Z)
            error(message('MATLAB:integral2:UnsupportedClass',class(Z)));
        end
        % Check that FUN is properly vectorized. This is important here
        % because we (otherwise) always pass in square matrices, which
        % reduces the probability of the user generating an error by
        % using matrix functions instead of elementwise functions.
        Z1 = FUN(X(VTSTIDX),Y(VTSTIDX)); NFE = NFE + 1;
        if ~isequal(size(Z),size(X)) || ~isequal(size(Z1),size(VTSTIDX))
            % Example:
            % integral2(@(x,y)1,0,1,0,1)
            error(message('MATLAB:integral2:funSizeMismatch'));
        end
```

Hope that information is detailed enough...I have no idea what happenes, because my example is exact as it is given on the mathworks site about `integral2`, isn't it?

Maybe I should precise a bit more, what I wanna do: since W_2D gives me a surface w(x,y) of a compactly supported 2-dimensional hat-function, stored in a matrix `w`, I want to calculate the volume between the (x,y)-plane and the surface z=w(x,y)...

EDIT2: I still do not understand how to handle the problem, that `integral2` creates matrices as inputs for my `W_1D`-functions, which are called in `W_2D` and intended to have a `<1xn double>`-valued input and return a `<1xn double>` output, but at least I can simply use the following to solve the integration over the tensor product by using two one-dimensional `integral`-calls, that is

```
V = integral(@(x)integral(@(y)W_1D(y,3,h),0,10).*W_1D(x,2,h),0,10);
```

Comment: It creates a matrix because every two points taken from the X and Y matrix are one point in the grid space. You can take only the column and the line from X and Y to use it on your function if that is what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This first function is quite wrong. You are not indexing the array positions while you are doing `w = x` inside for.

Besides, if that would work, you are returning a line vector, that is, size `1xlength(x)` and when you do w_x'*w_y you are doing `length(x)x1` times `1xlength(y)`, which would give you a matrix `length(x)*length(y)`.

Consider correcting your function:

```
function w = W_1D(x,pos)
   w = zeros(length(x),1); % Allocate w as column vector, so that the product gives a scalar (as I suppose that it is what you want.
   for ii=1:length(x) % Here, so that is indexes w and x elements as you need
       w(ii)=x(ii) - pos; % I changed your code to something that makes sense, but I don't know if that is what you want to do, you have to adapt it to work correctly.
   end
end
```

You may also want to debug your functions, consider adding `keyboard` before your operations and check what they are returning using `dbstep`. I.e:

```
function f = W_2D(x,y,pos_1,pos_2)
  w_x = W_1D(x,pos_1);
  w_y = W_1D(y,pos_2);
  keyboard
  f = w_x'*w_y;
end
```

Execution will stop at `keyboard`, then you can check `w_x` size, `w_y` size, and do `dbstep` to go after `f = w_x'*w_y` and see what it returned. After you finish debug, you can do `dbcont` so that it will continue execution.

This answer is a draft as it is quite difficult to help you with the information you have provided. But I think you can start working the things out with this. If you have more doubts feel free to ask.

Comment: I am very sorry, but I thought to keep the example function as short as possible would be better and didn't recognize the big mistake. Now there is the actual function I'm using.

Comment: @Mr.Kitopa this matlab line gives you a hint of what should be going on: `if ~isequal(size(Z),size(X)) || ~isequal(size(Z1),size(VTSTIDX))`. As it seems, your function should return a `14x14` matrix, that is Z (if I am right, it is the matrix returned by your function) should have the same size as the X and Y input. So, you should take care when calculating the `w`, so that you can have one value for each `x` and `y` input into your function.

Comment: Can you explain this a bit more, please? I don't know, how can I have a function which returns two values, when I want to make from two input vector one output matrix. That means, e.g. to the pair x(i) and y(j), there should be one value w(i,j). I could manage that with two for-loops, but I think, the tensor-product makes exactly that and is faster (because of vectorization)...or am I worng?

Comment: @Mr.Kitopa As yourself said, x and y are both <14x14 double>, the inputs are not vectors, they are a matrix of all grid points that it will use to estimate the integral. What I think your function should do is to return a <14x14> matrix representing the function answer for this grid, but you are returning a <154x192> matrix. Therefore, you need to work both of your functions, so that it works with the 14x14 grid points that is input, to return an answer grid of same size that makes sense (by making sense I mean that the function represents the values that it should for that point).

Comment: Ah ok, now I get it. But how is it possible, that `integral2` makes `x` and `y` to be nxn-matrices, when in `W_1D` they are only 1xn-vectors? In `W_2D` I call the 1-dimensional functions which return vectors...

Comment: @Mr.Kitopa you are wrong. If you go to W_2D in debug mode you will see that `x` and `y` are also <14x14> matrixes. It is your method `W_1D` that is not working with them properly, starting with `w=zeros(1,length(x));` which uses only the `length(x)`. As you are using indexes with only one index in: `xmpos(inds1)`, it will take only those index from the matrix. If you also check the returned `w_x`, it will be composed almost only by zeros, only the last 27 values are filled. I suggest you to work more on `W_1D` so that it returned the `w` as it should.

Comment: When I change the product, so that `w_x = transpose(w_x)` and then simple make a calculation `w_x*w_y`, it returns (in debug mode) for `x` and `y` AND `f`, resp. `X`, `Y` AND `Z` a `<14x14 double>`. But the error still occurs :(

Comment: It is strange, if you change your `f` to `f = x.^2+y.^2;` it will work, returning a 14x14 grid.

Comment: and you are right: `w_x` and `w_y` are both `<14x1 double>` resp. `<1x14 double>`, where `w_y` is filled with zeros. I think I got your hint now...thank you very much! :)